# Kolmogorov-Smirnov vs. Kuiper test

Tags: regression, nonparametric, kolmogorov-smirnov-test

I would like to compare two 2D distributions with quantitative variables, illustrated here:
[image]

For each "x", they are several measures "y".
I can't assume these distributions are parametric.

A Kolgomorov-Smirnov test (p=0) and a Kuiper test (p=0.5) give rise to very different results.

Could you please tell me in which cases a Kolgomorov-Smirnov test is more appropriate than a Kuiper test, and vice versa?

Thank you very much

Comment: You may find a good  [post](http://cxc.harvard.edu/csc/why/ks_test.html) on this subject. As far as I see, Kuiper test is insensitive on shifting, ie. if you shifting on of your distribution on x-axis, the result remains the same.